# Call dynamically named bundle from Frontend in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, caching, webpack.config.js

Inside `webpack.config.js`, i updated `bundle.js` name as following

```
output: { 
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/"),
    publicPath: "auto",
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
},
```

And i am calling it from frontend as following but it's giving error because now bundle.js name has been changed.

```
<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

How to call them properly?

Comment: the bundle filename is generated from transpilation , and the dist/index.html with the right include directive is generated from index.html.  We can not reply to your question, if you don't provide more details about your project setup.